# Excel file is not downloading using PHPExcel library with dynamic data

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, download, phpexcel

When I click on the export button, it goes to my `export_inquiry()` function and I have set my array which is coming from DB table and downloads the excel file with this dynamic array data. But, right now it throws me the error of
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://www.example.com/project_name/admin/order/export_inquiry might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

> ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

I am using `PHPExcel` library in `CodeIgniter` for downloading the excel file. Below is my code for excel export.

```
public function export_inquiry()
{
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $this->load->library('phpexcel/PHPExcel');
    $object = new PHPExcel();

      $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

      $table_columns = array("DATE", "ID", "CustomerReference", "InvoiceName", "PickUpCity", "PickUpDate");

      $column = 0;

      foreach($table_columns as $field)
      {
       $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);
       $column++;
      }

      $employee_data  =array(
        array(
            'order_date' => '2018-05-23 22:35:36',
            'id' => 17,
            'customerreference' => '',
            'invoice_name' => 'Troy Design and Manufacturing',
            'pick_up_city' => 'Gothenburg',
            'pick_up_date' => '2018-07-02'
        ),
        array(
            'order_date' => '2018-05-28 02:51:58',
            'id' => 19,
            'customerreference' => '',
            'invoice_name' => 'Hollingsworth Distribution Systems',
            'pick_up_city' => 'Gothenburg',
            'pick_up_date' => '2018-07-02'
        ),
        array(
            'order_date' => '2018-05-28 04:39:23',
            'id' => 20,
            'customerreference' => '',
            'invoice_name' => 'Motherson Automotive (FSP-1)',
            'pick_up_city' => 'Gothenburg',
            'pick_up_date' => '2018-07-02'
        )
    );

      $excel_row = 2;
      foreach($employee_data as $key => $row)
      {
       $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $row['order_date']);
       $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, $row['id']);
       $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $row['customerreference']);
       $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $excel_row, $row['invoice_name']);
       $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $excel_row, $row['pick_up_city']);
       $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $excel_row, $row['pick_up_date']);
       $excel_row++;
      }

      $object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
      header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Employee Data.xls"');
      $object_writer->save('php://output');
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will helpful to your issue.Please check it...

---

```
public function export_inquiry() {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

        $this->load->library('phpexcel/PHPExcel');

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  

        $employee_data  =array(
            array(
                'order_date' => '2018-05-23 22:35:36',
                'id' => 17,
                'customerreference' => '',
                'invoice_name' => 'Troy Design and Manufacturing',
                'pick_up_city' => 'Gothenburg',
                'pick_up_date' => '2018-07-02'
            ),
            array(
                'order_date' => '2018-05-28 02:51:58',
                'id' => 19,
                'customerreference' => '',
                'invoice_name' => 'Hollingsworth Distribution Systems',
                'pick_up_city' => 'Gothenburg',
                'pick_up_date' => '2018-07-02'
            ),
            array(
                'order_date' => '2018-05-28 04:39:23',
                'id' => 20,
                'customerreference' => '',
                'invoice_name' => 'Motherson Automotive (FSP-1)',
                'pick_up_city' => 'Gothenburg',
                'pick_up_date' => '2018-07-02'
            )
        );      

        // Add some data
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A1', 'ID')
                    ->setCellValue('B1', 'Order date')
                    ->setCellValue('C1', 'Customer reference')
                    ->setCellValue('D1', 'Invoice name')
                    ->setCellValue('E1', 'Pick up city')
                    ->setCellValue('F1', 'Pick up date');

        $i = 2;
        foreach ($employee_data as $key => $value) {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, ($key + 1))
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, ($value['order_date'] ? date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value['order_date'])) : "-"))
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, ($value['customerreference'] ? : "-"))
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, ($value['invoice_name'] ? : "-"))
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, ($value['pick_up_city'] ? : "-"))
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, ($value['pick_up_date'] ? date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value['pick_up_date'])) : "-"));                  
            $i++;

        }

        // Rename worksheet
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Report - '.date("d-m-Y"));
        // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
        $file_name = time().".xls";
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$file_name.'');    
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;
    }
```